# zip file download not working in ipad Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, ipad, safari

I have java web application running on JBoss server.

When I tried to download zip file from iPad using chrome then chrome can not download zip file and tad continues loading.

Same this works fine with iPad using Safari.
Here is response header:

[image]

Also this is works fine with pdf, text and other file which chrome can open in inline tab.

I am using `Version 58.0.3029.83` on my iPad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in chrome. You can find out more information and status [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721862)